# Using for loop indices in variable generation SAS

Tags: for-loop, sas

I would like to set up a for loop in SAS where I would like to create time dependent tables.

The idea is rather simple. I have multiple tables where I would like to left join them and i would like to this operation for every month. I dont have too much experince in SAS coding so I would really appreciate your help. The idea i have is as follows:

```
for i in [201401:201503]
proc sql;
create table try_i ## for each month try_201401, try_201402 etc...
select t1.var1 as var1_i ##again similar to above var1_201401, var_201402 etc..
from t1 
left join table2 t2 on condition1 ## this is not dependennt so there is index is required   
...
where t1.var'i' is not missinig ## in table t1, I have a specific variable which specifies the time period ex: var201405
```

Thanks a lot in advance 
Turan

Comment: This is discussed fairly frequently on this site, and the same caveat always needs to be given: most of the time, this is not a good idea.  You can usually do the same analysis more easily with a single table with a BY statement by the month/year (or whatever you wish to do the analysis by) than multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple macro would do:

```
%macro monthly_table( year, month);
   proc sql;
   create table as try_&year.&month. as
   select t1.var1 as var&year.&month. from t1
   left join .... on...
   where t1.var&year.&month. is not missing;
   quit;
%mend monthlytable;

%macro reporting( year,month);
  %do month =1 to &month;
      %monthly_table( &year, &month)
  end;
%mend reporting;
```

In case you do not familiar with macro:

**The macro monthly_ table :**
  `%macro % mend` are used to define the macro, and &year &month would return the value you supply between the parentheses at the first line.

e.g. `%monthlyRep ( 2004, 01)` would run the proc sql statement based on the year value = 2004 and month value =  01.

**The macro Reporting :**
loop through the months in a year. 
for 2015, you just have to specify within the parentheses e.g.

```
%report( 2015, 01) = 201501
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer. I tried and it works

Comment: I also changed some minor codes; such as %mend monthlytable -> %mend monthly_table.